# How can I get rid of vertical white space and a horizontal scrollbar WITHOUT adding a second vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html

My website has some annoying white space on the right side and a horizontal scrollbar. I found help with some css code that got rid of the white space and the horizontal scrollbar. However, this code creates a second vertical scrollbar. So I'm stuck with either one or the other. How can I get rid of both additional scrollbars?

This is the code that eliminated the first problem but created the second problem.

```
html,
body{
width:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: To remove scrollbars entirely for a specific element check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Uz7wc) or post your code to find out what the actual problem it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I'm a complete newbie and I don't understand anything from the link you provided. Can you share a line of code that gets rid of the horizontal scrollbar without adding a second vertical scrollbar? Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot give you a specific reply because i don't fully understand your implementation, maybe you can add a link to your website or a sample image on the post.

Comment: add padding:0 probably. Link your site and we'd be able to be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

You should add a screenshots of your website so we can understand better.

Don't overflow though body and HTML, but try with class name or id.

Select proper class name, this code will definitely work:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:hidden;
margin-right:0;
padding-right:0;
```

If you can't select the correct class

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) You could try adding a margin: 0 and removing the overflow-x: hidden
Your css would be this:

```
        html,
        body{
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        }
```

I hope this will help you.